# All data on SD card wiped after device reboot

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, 7.0-nougat, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

Today I switched my phone on (Micromax Bharat 3) after a couple of days and saw, to my surprise, that all the data on my SD card (which is formatted as internal storage) had disappeared. Data for all my apps had gone, including a large collection of pictures. I took a couple of photos and screenshots, restarted my phone, and those disappeared too. This is not something which has happened before in the couple of months that I have owned this phone for.

When I go into storage settings, it shows me that my SD card is about 8GB full, but neither the phone's file explorer nor ES file explorer show me enough files to fill even 1 GB, which leads me to believe that my files are still hidden there somewhere.

DiskDigger was unable to recover any photos or any of the data; nothing showed up in the scan.

Keep in mind that my phone is *not* rooted, and has not been updated recently.

I noticed something strange when I first switched my phone this morning though. My SD card wasn't detected and I got a notification to insert if for proper functioning of apps (since it's formatted as internal storage and some apps are/were installed on it). When I restarted my phone the notification went away and the card was detected so I didn't pay much attention to it then.

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can get my photos back? My phone is running near stock Android Nougat. Since the SD card is formatted as internal storage, I can't recover any files from my PC.

Comment: IT JUST HAPPENED AGAIN SOMEBODY HALP

Comment: See the tag of adoptable-storage (added to your question) , which would help you